# Subset of a metric space is a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I have a question? Why is it that every subset of a metric space is a metric space? I mean what if the subset is the empty set, then it can't be a metric space, right? because a metric space is by definition a non-empty set. So would I be correct to say that every non-empty subset of a metric space is a metric space? But i'm confused because since compact sets are metric spaces, and every finite set is a compact set, doesn't that mean that the empty set is compact? Therefore a metric space by definition?

Comment: I guess it's possible, but "my" definition of metric space allows $\emptyset$.  Not that it matters.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of metric space. The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) that I am familiar with allows the empty set. Either way I think this is not an important question to ask since the empty set is not an interesting space...

Comment: I will always laugh at whoever it was here that had that story from their grad school years about "the keeper of the empty set."

Comment: @angryavian what if I wanted to prove that a subset of a metric space has a following property that for every element in the set P(x), how would I do that if the empty set is a subset? would I be incorrect to say that if I have something that said Let S $\subset$ X. Prove $\forall x \in S$ P(x), then I must only consider the non- empty sets? or is it still true vacously? what about $\forall x \in S \exists$? or $\exists$.....

Comment: It's true vacuously, but no one cares.  It's not going to suddenly prove some great big theorem because you can apply it to the empty set.

Comment: @Randall oh so do people usually leave out a proof for the empty set?

Comment: Usually, yes, because it's trivial and only clutters up your writing.  If I'm mature enough to read a paper I don't need an empty argument spelled out for me.

Comment: Compact sets are not necessarily metric spaces. Even a non-empty compact Hausdorff space may  have a topology that cannot be generated by a  metric.

Answer (score 1):

I think a metric space can be empty, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Comment: Yes. Or see General Topology by R. Engelking, or almost any  random textbook on  the subject.